# "In order that" or "In order to"

Tags: verbs, sentence-structure, subjunctives

I stumbled across this example sentence in Wikipedia: "I braked **in order that** the car **stay** on the road," and immediately thought what I would've said would be: "I braked **so that** the car **would stay** on the road," or maybe "I braked **in order for** the car **to stay** on the road" instead, though there is a strange ring to the last one. Which one(s) is not correct and why not?

Comment: For an explanation, google *subjunctive*:  Useful guidance at: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/when-to-use-the-subjunctive

Comment: They're all fine.

Comment: Please give a link to the Wikipedia page and some of the relevant text. It is always easier to answer if you give us the full information.

Comment: This was a while ago and I don't remember where I saw it, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

"I braked in order that the car stay on the road,"

I haven't heard this kind of use of the subjunctive in English since learning Latin at school. It helped us to understand the Latin subjunctive. No-one that I know of writes or speaks like this. It's correct but not idiomatic - especially not in the 21st century.

Answer (score 0):

In order that is perfectly fine, the only problem with your sentence though, is that you should use "stays" instead of "stay" as the car is singular third person. Though this is not the case for "in order for".

Answer (score 0):

In order that is pretty good, however, for clarity, I would write it as "I braked so that the car would stay on the road."